# How to link static library .o files?

Tags: c, linker, ld

I'm experimenting with my first foray into libraries. I am trying to compile the Unity testing framework to a static library using `gcc -c -fPIC -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror -Wmissing-declarations -DUNITY_SUPPORT_64 test-framework/unity.c  -o bin/libunity.o`

This runs just fine.

However when I then try to use that object file:

```
$ gcc test_hello_world.c -Lbin -lunity -o test
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lunity
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Checking what ld is doing

```
$  ld -Lbin -luinty --verbose
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34
  Supported emulations:
   elf_x86_64
   elf32_x86_64
#
# ... script waffle
#
==================================================
ld: mode elf_x86_64
attempt to open bin/libuinty.so failed
attempt to open bin/libuinty.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuinty.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuinty.a failed
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuinty.so failed
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuinty.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuinty.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuinty.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu64/libuinty.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu64/libuinty.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/libuinty.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/libuinty.a failed
attempt to open /lib64/libuinty.so failed
attempt to open /lib64/libuinty.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libuinty.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libuinty.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libuinty.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libuinty.a failed
attempt to open /lib/libuinty.so failed
attempt to open /lib/libuinty.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libuinty.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libuinty.a failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libuinty.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libuinty.a failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libuinty.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libuinty.a failed
ld: cannot find -luinty
```

So it looks for `bin/libunity.so` and `bin/libunity.a`, but no `bin/libunity.o`... every internet page I've looked at this evening seems to assume  that ld should pick up ".o" files just the same as ".so" or ".a" no questions asked (man pages seem to either similarly expect it or don't mention ".o" at all)... but it's not...

Am I misunderstanding something? Missing some argument?

EDIT: I've now run `ar rcs bin/libunity.a bin/unity.o` and then the `gcc` command from above. This *seems* to work (there are other errors). But I still thought ld should work with .o files, am I, and half the web, wrong?

Comment: `gcc test_hello_world.c  bin/libunity.o -o test` should work. Never heard of `lib*.o` files being subsitutable for `lib*.so`/`lib*.a` files. `*.o` files are linked directly. No `lib*foo.o` => `-lfoo` magic.

Comment: I would hesitate to even use the word "library" to describe a .o file.  If you find that "half the web" is calling a .o file a library, then I would agree that half the web is wrong.

Comment: Or if you want to turn your `.o` into an `.a`, `ar -crs libunity.a libunity.o`, [See also](https://www.howtogeek.com/427086/how-to-use-linuxs-ar-command-to-create-static-libraries/). A static library is an `ar` archive containing one or more object files.

Comment: But I would be very surprised if half the web is wrong.  More like 95% is incorrect.

Comment: Half the web may be *slight hyperbole :D, the 6-7 sites I checked all disagreed with each other, but all expected .o files to link OK.

Comment: Closing as my EDIT answers the main question. Comments confirm I was just being silly :D.

Comment: The first comment addresses your main question. The special argument for .o files is nothing, just add their file names to the command line.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @PSkocik, could you make your comment an answer?

Comment: In addition to all the other answers, you should _never_ use `ld` directly on a UNIX system (unless you are linking an OS kernel or a boot loader). _Always_ use appropriate compiler front end (`gcc` here) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$ gcc test_hello_world.c bin/libunity.o -o test
```

Possibly shouldn't even really use the word "library" to describe a `*.o` file.
Never heard of `lib*.o` files being suitable for `lib*.so`/`lib*.a` files.
`*.o` files are linked directly without any `libfoo.o` ==> `-lfoo` magic.

Or if you want to turn `.o` into a `.a`, then use `$ ar -crs libunity.a libunity.o`, (see also: https://www.howtogeek.com/427086/how-to-use-linuxs-ar-command-to-create-static-libraries/).
A static library is an `ar` archive containing one or more object files.